# Why is my choropleth gradient in Leaflet inaccurate?

Tags: r, leaflet, choropleth, gradient

I am trying to plot a choropleth using shape files and leaflet. I merged a population column to the shape file data frame, and used that column to base the gradient on. The merge was successful in that the population matched correctly with the counties.

```
leaflet(data = countiesshp) %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
addPolygons(fillColor =~colorQuantile("Greens", countiesshp@data$population.y)(countiesshp@data$population.y),
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          color = 'Black',
          weight = 1)
```

When I get the output, I can clearly see gradient is not working properly.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGrzz.jpg)

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbKfN.jpg)

As you can see, Parks county has a very low population, but the gradient would indicate that it is very high. Arapahoe county has a high population but the gradient would indicate that it is very low. I would really appreciate any help with this! Thanks!

Edit: When I added the hover functionality, I can see that the wrong data is being read for each county, for example when I hover over Arapahoe county, CO it shows 15,242 instead of 572,003. I added image 3 to show this
[Arapahoe hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R76p0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data its difficult to determine what the exact problem is but here are two ideas:

1 - It appears you are reading in the populations as strings i.e. "572,003" for Arapahoe County when these should be converted to numeric.

2 - Try using `sp::merge` for the `merge` function specifically developed for merging SPDFs

I modified your code a bit to make a more reproducible example:

```
coshp <- tigris::counties(state = "Colorado")

library(leaflet)

data <- data.frame(NAME = c("Arapahoe", "Boulder", "Clear Creek", "Larimer"),
                   population = c("572,003", "294,567", "9,088", "299,630"))
data$population <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data$population))

coshp_merged <- sp::merge(coshp, data)

leaflet(data = coshp_merged) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor =~colorQuantile("Greens", coshp_merged$population)(coshp_merged$population),
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              color = 'Black',
              weight = 1)
```

Which yielded this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I needed to do the sp::merge